# How to add another condition in php

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I had been trying this for very long . But i couldn't succeed so i need your kind help .

In another file I had submitted my entries into databse with no problems .Now i created a file ppp.html file to help user update database .
here is ppp.html

```
<html>
  <form action="l.php" method="post">
    <input type ="text" name ="complaint">
    <input type="text" name="dte"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
  </form>
</html>
```

I diverted the file to l.php .The function of l.php will be to show data from database . i have added one condition in query where category=$complaint .it works properly but now i need two conditions where category =$complaint and also where dte=$date 
How to do that . Here is l.php file

```
<?php
$complaint = "";
if (isset($_POST['complaint'])) {
    $complaint = $_POST['complaint'];
}

$dte = "";
if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
    $dte = $_POST['date'];
}

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("couldnt attack ");
mysql_select_db("site")or die('i surrender');
$query = ("SELECT * FROM site2 where category='$complaint'") or die("couldnt select");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('hghyt');
while ($complaint = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo"<td>" . '<br>' . $complaint['category'] . "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" . '<br>' . $complaint['quantity'] . "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" . '<br>' . $complaint['place'] . "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" . '<br>' . $complaint['dte'] . "</tr>";
    ECHO"<TR>" . "<A HREF='update.php?complaint=" . $complaint['category'] . "'>" . "UPDATE" . "</A>";
    echo "<br/>";
    ECHO"</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: An aside. I don't think the `<form>` tag is self closing, so you should close it in your HTML. Also, be consistent with your closing of the `<input>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add AND to the SQL statement. Like this:

```
("SELECT * FROM site2 where category='$complaint' AND dte='$dte'");
```

You should always escape or bind your variables in order to protect yourself from SQL injection.
For further reading about SQL injection: [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

You shouldn't even be using mysql_*.
Read this: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Edit:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM site2 where category='$complaint' AND dte='$dte'";
```

Comment: i am getting error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR) in C:\xampp\htdocs\site 155b\l.php on line 18

Comment: You are using "or die" in the wrong place. Remove that line and replace with my edit.

Comment: Then you have a problem with the database. Make sure the table "site2" exists.

Comment: sir ,its definitely exist  ..DATABSE NAME ="SITE" AND TABLE NAME = "SITE2" ..... coding is tough :(

Comment: Yea I know it is, but dont give up. What is the values of $complaint and $dte?

Comment: if i only place $category=$complaint ,its working then ...., surprised .I just removed dte=$dte and it worked ..

Comment: I think there is a problem with the column "dte" or the variable $dte. Make sure they are correct.

Comment: You are welcome. Please visit the links in my answer to stay updated and secured from threats. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `AND` to your `WHERE` conditions like this:

`$query=("SELECT * FROM site2 WHERE category='$complaint'" AND dte='$dte'")`

But you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR) in C:\xampp\htdocs\site 155b\l.php on line 18

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryString ='';
$complaint = "";
if (isset($_POST['complaint'])) {
    $complaint = $_POST['complaint'];
    $queryString = "where category='$complaint'";
}

$dte = "";
if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
    $dte = $_POST['date'];
    if($queryString==""){
$queryString = "where dte='$dte'";
}else{
$queryString .= "and dte='$dte'";
}



mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("couldnt attack ");
mysql_select_db("site")or die('i surrender');
$query = ("SELECT * FROM site2 $queryString") or die("couldnt select");
```